# How do I prevent my 'insert' query from inserting duplicates in mariadb?

Tags: php, duplicates, mariadb, sql-insert

I wrote this code to collect post info via a form and insert it into my database and it's definitely doing its job. The problem is that each time the code is executed, it inserts multiple duplicates of the information gotten from the form. Any idea how to stop this from happening? Here's a code snippet for context:

```
$query= $connect->prepare("insert into posts (title,date,author,content,image) values('$title','$date','$author','$content','$fileNameNew');");
$query->execute();

if($query->execute()){
    echo('POST UPLOADED SUCESSFULLY');
    $query->close();  
}else{
    echo('POST UPLOADED HAS FAILED');
}
```

Comment: This code can't do that. You must be running it multiple times for some reason.

Comment: If you're submitting the data using AJAX, make sure you've disabled the default form submission.

Comment: If you're using a traditional form, redirect to a page after submitting the form to clear the post data from the request.

Comment: @waterloomatt Just did that and it still keeps uploading duplicates

Comment: @Barmar I'm only running it once and also not using ajax

Comment: If you were only running it once it would only insert once. Check your server access log to see how many times the script is being called.

Comment: @Barmar In a way you were right. The query was being run twice . Removing 'query->execute()' seems to have done the trick. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that myself -- I've seen this mistake dozens of times before.

Answer (score 0):

For prevent insert duplication you can use next code:

```
$query = $connect->prepare("insert into posts (title,date,author,content,image) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");

if($query->execute([$title,$date,$author,$content,$fileNameNew])){
    echo('POST UPLOADED SUCESSFULLY');
}else{
    echo('POST UPLOADED HAS FAILED');
}
```

[PHP PDO test online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=324d091ed2306e9fe2d9c839f14309a4&sqlses=71eee4fb004728b98d13cf6bb209ae32&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Also this code use parameters in prepared statement for prevent SQL Injection